# Failing to firebase deploy secondary hosting site

Tags: reactjs, firebase-hosting

I am attempting to deploy my React.js project to a secondary `dev` hosting site on Firebase, but I am getting `Error: Task ab14... failed: retries exhausted after 6 attempts` after running the command `firebase deploy --only hosting:dev`.

As I have done successfully on another project, I setup hosting by running: `firebase target:apply hosting dev dev-sitename-com` then `firebase target:apply hosting live live-sitename-com` to apply each site. Then I change `firebase.json` from

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  }
}
```

**TO**

```
{
  "hosting": [ 
    {
      "target": "live",
      "public": "build",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "target": "dev",
      "public": "build",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  }
}
```

I've deleted node_modules and reinstalled. I've deleted the build folder and rebuilt. I've tried setting GENERATE_SOURCEMAP from false to true. I can still deploy to the `live` target, but not `dev`, which should be indicative of the issue. Looks like some others with the same issue had the issue resolve over a few hours as it was on firebase's side, but I doubt is the issue because live will deploy. From the logs it looks like the deploy is getting stuck on uploading the last 2 files. The logs also indicate `The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined at validateString (internal/validators.js:107:11)`, which isn't directing anywhere in my code. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here are the logs for --debug when deploying: https://pastebin.com/xhPZFnzr

Comment: Any resolution? I've encountered the same issue.

Comment: @AndrewBurnett does this other thread the same issue? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60699826/firebase-hosting-deploy-error-task-5fc-failed-retries-exhausted-after-6-att/65332659#65332659) 

I think I made another question because this question was flagged and it didn't post, but I guess it still went through? Not sure, but might flag as duplicate.

Comment: I realized I'm encountering a similar but slightly different issue. I'm trying to deploy my app to two different Firebase projects (environments dev & prod) via the 'use' command. I'm encountering an error as it attempts to upload the last 5 or so files.

Comment: @AndrewBurnett sounds the same to me, when I was working through the bug, I remember sometimes it would be 5 files it failed on, sometimes 9, etc. The `use` command is used just to setup the aliases, and is used twice to setup aliases in the `.firebaserc` file (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#add_alias)

Comment: Ok, so the issue is unrelated to the actual deployment commands. How did you ultimately solve the issue? Mine deploys fine to one project but not at all to the other.

Comment: Pretty sure you just use the flag like so for commands `firebase deploy --project=alias-name`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue doing the following:

- update firebase cli and run firebase init
- delete .firebase cache folder